# Change background color in navigation menu using CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I need to change background color of the navigation menu specified by this [CSS](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) file (it's used in this [Jquery example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Example)). I cannot figure out where is this line. Please help.

Comment: use webdevelopment tools : Firebug for Firefox, Developer tools for Chrome ... right click on the element you want to change as background and trace the css

Comment: Yeah,it helped a lot. I would accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it was just a tip, not an actual answer and I'm not reputation junkie at all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the class you need to change is called ***'.ui-widget-header'***, and it looks like this:

```
.ui-widget-header
{
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #cccccc url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Simply open your CSS file in any editor, use the Find function (*usually CTRL + F*) and look for ***'.ui-widget-header'*.** Then you can change the background color and image if you have basic CSS knowledge. If not, please ask for assistance.

As **@drinchev** said, in the future if you need to find a specific element just mouse over it and use 'Inspect Element', assuming you are using newer versions of Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome. In case you are using Internet Exporer, press F12 and use the '*Select Element*' pointer over the needed item.

You can also dynamically change values with those Developer Tools to see how would it look like if you made the changes for real.

P.S.: Keep in mind that I reformatted the CSS a bit, because it was put in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Use inspect element on chrome or the Firebug for Firefox.
Click on the element to obtain all the css styles and their parent styles. Change the value directly by double clicking & check for the result once.